# Emberjs route is unable to access authenticated user

Tags: ember.js, firebase, torii

My Ember app will show user's information after they are authenticated.  I am doing authentication with Firebase and the user the is being authenticated, but the route seems to trying to find the user before this happens.  It gives me this error:

```
Assertion Failed: You cannot pass `undefined` as id to the store's find method
```

Any idea how to fix this/ why it is happening?

Here is my application route with the login function:

```
login: function(email, password) {
           this.get('session').open('firebase', {
                provider: 'password',
                email: email,
                password: password
           }).then(function() {
               this.transitionTo('index');
           }.bind(this));
       },
       logout: function() {
           this.get('session').close().then(function() {
               this.transitionTo('application');
           }.bind(this));
       }
```

Here is my index route:

```
  model: function(params){
        return this.store.find('user', params.user_id);
}
```

Comment: do you have dynamic segments for the `user` route.. this.route('user',{path:':user_id})   in router.js

Comment: I can get it to work when I do that but is there any way to have it work with just the index route so the root can be the domain when the user logs in? @kumkanillam

Comment: which index route ? and don't you want to show url with  user_id ? show me the URL, so that we can update router configuration to adapt it.

Comment: This may be a dumb question but my goal is to, after login, redirect to the user specific homepage with that users information but have it at path "/"

Comment: @kumkanillam the URL I'm having trouble with is path: "/"

Comment: There is no `params.user_id` what do you expect?

Comment: @Kitler is there a way I can pass the params.user_id to the route without it being the URL?

Comment: Create a service, after authenticating set a property (something like currentUser) and have it store the id, you will be able to inject that service in routes and get the id from it.

Comment: @Kitler This worked perfectly! Would you mind adding your comment as an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: @NickEmmons give https://github.com/Vestorly/torii#router-dsl a read, especially the part where they return the currentUser